# Separate table creation at runtime or add column

Tags: table, identity

I am planning to keep patient data in a patient table. I will have multiple Clients registered with me, and each client will have multiple doctors. Should I make patient table client wise or a single table with client and doctor ID field?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you provide us with examples of your alternatives?

Comment: I think OP is taking about some health care application Database which supports multiple clinics

Answer (score 0):

It is better to have single `patient` table.

Each doctor must have different `UserId`(or call PhysicianId) and then make entry in `patient` table with `FkPhysicianId` as a column and you can have one table for storing clinic information(auto incremented key can be used as `ClinicId)` and one for storing physicians Information like `ClinicId` etc.

single patient table will be better as you don't need to add table for each practice you add and data can queried using joins on these table and maintaining too many table in future will be problomatic and other implementation in the EMR application as well.

I would suggest to have a Master Table to assign auto incremented Id to `physician` and `patient` as well.